# format sealed type parameterized trait with Playframework json

Tags: json, scala, deserialization, playframework-2.6

I have type parameterized sealed trait

```
sealed trait PropertyValue[T <: Property]
```

I need write `format` for Json serialization/deserialization.
I try

```
implicit def format[P <: Property : Format]: Format[PropertyValue[P]] = {
    Format(
      Reads(j =>
        Json.fromJson[StringPropertyValue](j)
          .orElse(Json.fromJson[NumberPropertyValue](j))
          .orElse(JsError("Undefined type"))
      ),
      Writes(o => Json.toJson(o))
    )
  }
```

but I have

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Product with Serializable with PropertyValue[_ >: StringProperty with NumberProperty <: Product with Serializable with Property]]
[error]  required: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[PropertyValue[P]]
```

Is there any way for implementinng `Reads[trait[T]]` for type parameterized trait?

Comment: I don't understand who are you going to use it. What the return type of the parsing would be? `PropertyValue[P]`? And who's going to fill the `P` there? It should be known at the compile time so it can't depend on the runtime value. I don't understand how are you going to use a `format` with such signature. Could you provide an example? And to make it compilable just substitute `format` implementation with `???`.

Comment: I agree with you. Serialization/Deserialization must be for concrete classes or for sealed traits (controlled inheritance). Traits and some other type parameterized (class or trait) cannot be deserialized. But on other hand List[A] can be (de)serialized.

Comment: Sorry List[A] (de)serialized to List, but my trait (de)serialized to concrete inherited class. These are different examples.

Comment: I think Type member can help in such place.

Comment: Andrey, I don't think you get my point. It is not about inheritance, it is about generics. You can decode `List[String]` or `List[SomeObject]` but you can't decode `List[A]`. `A` has to be known at the compile time.  Similarly you can decode `SealedTrait` but not `SealedTrait[A]` because again `A` has to be known at the compile time. Compiler does its type safety checks by definition at the compile time. This is when all the types (including the generic components) has to be known. You can probably decode `List[_]` or `SealedTrait[_]` but that's kind of defeat the whole type safety.